# Mapbox vector tile not displaying in QGIS, possibly due to unsupported data type

Tags: qgis, tippecanoe, mapbox-vector-tile, protobuf

I created a Mapbox Vector Tile collection in .mbtiles format using [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe). Using the QGIS browser I can add the .mbtiles file as a layer and I see the data as expected, so I know the .mbtiles file is fine.

My application requires each of the vector tiles to be served separately via z/x/y URL paths, so I have to unpack the .mbtiles file.

I extracted all tiles with `mb-util --image_format=pbf filename.mbtiles output_directory`. This created the expected directory / file structure, e.g. `5/4/11.pbf`.
I started a local HTTP server within `output_directory` and added the local URL to QGIS under "Vector Tiles" -> "New Generic Collection". Unfortunately QGIS does not render any vector tiles, even though it does appear to successfully retrieve data over HTTP. The QGIS network log shows many HTTP 200 "OK" responses from my local HTTP server and the correct `Content-Length` value, so I'm confident that QGIS is accessing the tiles. QGIS is not providing any feedback on what the problem could be, even in the Log Messages panel.

In an effort to debug the problem I tried using [mvtview](https://github.com/mapbox/mvtview). mvtview crashes when I attempt to view a tile with `mvtview output_directory/5/4/11.pbf`. The error is thrown [here](https://github.com/mapbox/pbf/blob/main/index.js#L211) within the `pbf` package and *I think* this means my vector tile has a field (presumably an attribute) with an unsupported data type. The logic within the `skip` function appears to move a pointer to the end of a field, but cannot determine how many bytes to jump for a field in my tile. The unsupported type is `3`, which is missing from the list of supported types [here](https://github.com/mapbox/pbf/blob/bfaaa5daea7e2a57e5e0b22cca75037113000e33/index.js#L14). I'm having trouble figuring out what `3` might be.

I've removed all attributes except one from the source data, and that remaining attribute is type `QString` or `String` according to QGIS. I'm currently unsure how to debug the issue further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With further research I discovered the error I received is often a sign that the tiles need to be decompressed before being read. I had not applied any compression, and my local HTTP server was not configured to compress tiles for transit, but tippecanoe applies compression by default. I addressed the issue by adding `--no-tile-compression` to my tippecanoe command.

Comment: Is this now flipped? - Does QGIS now require compression? Anyone have ideas? I have a vector tile generation tool written in Node and currently without compression the mbtiles show no data - however when I turn on compression the tiles show up.